# Java: encontrar arquivos em diretório

Tags: java, arquivo, algoritmo-de-busca

Eu tenho uma função simples para buscar um arquivo no diretório da aplicação e retornar ele, entanto o retorno sempre está sendo vazio, não encontrei onde está o erro.

```
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get(""); 
        String url = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "/uploads"; 
        File dir = new File(url);
       //pego o caminho atual e concateno com a pasta que quero, onde está o arquivo txt.

           File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
            {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
                {
                    //return name.startsWith("file") && name.endsWith(".txt");
                    return name.equals("file.txt");

                   //nenhuma das opções de retorno encontra arquivos.
                }
            });
```

Agradeço contribuições.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No primeiro `return` já está ok, vc só precisa iterar no vetor de `File[]` e pegar os valores, como fiz abaixo.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class getFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
        String url = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "/uploads"; 
        File dir = new File(url);
       //pego o caminho atual e concateno com a pasta que quero, onde está o arquivo txt.

        File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
            {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
                {
                    return name.startsWith("file") && name.endsWith(".txt");
                }
            });

        for(File f : matches) {
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá, coloque o código na resposta e não a imagem. Desta forma não facilita para outros usuários testarem seu código.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigada !